# Python, сохранение значения переменной функции

Tags: python, функции

Программа находит площадь комнаты БЕЗ учета пола и потолка по введенным параметрам (функция `sqrRoom`), затем вычисляется площадь, занимаемая окнами и дверями и вычитается из площади комнаты (функции `newSqrRoom` и `sqrWD`). Вычисляется площадь одного рулона обоев по введенным параметрам и находится количество рулонов обоев, необходимых для оклейки (функции `sqrOboi` и `numOfOboi`).

```
'''d, D - door
   w, W - window
'''

'''глобальная переменная для хранения плрщади комнаты'''
sqrR=None
def sqrRoom():
    '''Нахождение площади комнаты БЕЗ учета пола и потолка и возвращение ее значения'''

    l=int(input('enter lenght of room'))
    w=int(input('enter weigth of room'))
    h=int(input('enter height of room'))

    global sqrR
    sqrR=2 * h * (l + w)

    return sqrR

def newSqrRoom():
    '''Нахождение новой плащади комнаты С учетом плащади окон и дверей
       Возвращение новой площади
    '''

    return  sqrR - sqr

def numOfOboi():
    '''Рассчет количества рулонов обоев для оклейки комнаты новой площади
       Возвращение количества рулонов
    '''

    return round(newSqrRoom() / sqrO, 2)

'''глобальная переменная для хранения площади, занимаемой окнами и дверями'''
sqr=None
def sqrWD():
    '''Запрос количества дверей и окон (nd, nw)
       Введение параметров дверей и окон(ld, hd, lw, hw) в циклах for и нахождение их площадей
       Добавление площадей в счетчик sqr общей площади окон и дверей
       Возвращение площади
    '''

    global sqr
    sqr = 0

    nd = int(input('enter number of door'))

    for i in range(nd):
        ld = int(input('enter length of door'))
        hd = int(input('enter height of door'))
        sqr += ld * hd

    nw = int(input('enter number of window'))

    for i in range (nw):
        lw = int(input('enter length of window'))
        hw = int(input('enter height of window'))
        sqr += lw * hw

    return sqr

'''глобальная переменная для хранения площади одного рулона обоев'''
sqrO=None
def sqrOboi():
    '''Введение параметров для одого рулона обоев
       Нахождение площади одного рулона
       Возващение значения площади
    '''

    l=int(input('enter length of oboi'))
    h=int(input('enter height of oboi'))

    global sqrO
    sqrO = l * h

    return sqrO

def outPut():
    '''Вывод площади комнаты
       Вывод новой площади комнаты
       Вывод количества рулонов для оклейки
    '''

    sqrRoom()
    sqrWD()
    sqrOboi()
    print('------------------------------------------------------')
    print('square of room: ', sqrR)
    print('new sqaure of room: ', newSqrRoom())
    print('you need ', numOfOboi(),' rylonov oboev')

outPut()
```

Я использовал глобальные переменные, но хотелось бы сделать все без них данным образом:

```
def setA():
    A=int(input('enter'))
    return A

def setB():
    B=int(input('enter'))
    return B

def sum():
    s=setA()+setB()
    return s

def mul():
    m=setA()*5

def output():
    print(sum())
    print(mul())
```

В функции `output` при вызове в конечном итоге в функции `setA` запрашивается значение `A`. Затем запрашивается значение `B` и находится их сумма. Далее в `output` вызывается `mul`, где происходит умножение `A` на 5. Однако, снова вызывается функция для объявления значения, но мне нужно, чтобы значение переменной а сохранялось. Каким образом это сделать БЕЗ использования глобальных переменных?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте аргументы в функциях (https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/vse-o-funkciyax-i-ix-argumentax.html)

```
l=int(input('enter lenght of room'))
w=int(input('enter weigth of room'))
h=int(input('enter height of room'))

def sqrRoom(h, l, v)
    return 2 * h * (l + w)

print('square of room: ', sqrRoom(h, l, w))
```

Answer (score 0):

Храните значения в функции output.

```
sqr_r = sqrRoom()
sqr_aperture = sqrWD()
sqr_wallpaper = sqrOboi()

sqr_wall = sqr_r - sqr_aperture
wallpaper_count = round(sqr_wall / sqr_wallpaper, 2)
```

Если логика потребует дальнейшего использования промежуточных данных, смотреть в сторону объектного подхода. Выделив классы room, aperture, wallpaper, который будут хранить исходные данные, длины и ширины, а площади и количества, выдавать методами.